# how to add conditional styles?

Tags: 7

How can I insert the following:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <style type='text/css'>
  #page{display: none;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

I tried it in page.tpl.php but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `html.tpl.php` also it work in `page.tpl.php` but I think you did not clear cache , please dont forget this, clear cache after `templates` changes.

also you can use conditional css 
this link help you

https://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles

Comment: I cleared the cache ctrl+f5 but not changed...

Comment: do you try to put it in html.tpl.php?

Comment: yes, tried that too....

Comment: would you please add that part of code in your question ?

Comment: what part? the exact code as in the question I placed in html.tpl.php in head.....

Comment: yes,that part with some line after and before

Comment: before the closing of head tag, also tried right after title tag...

Comment: But I've copied the html.tpl.php to my subtheme from the base theme...

Comment: I tried conditional-styles just now but still having no change... I think compatibility mode doesn't change in ie?

Comment: Ctrl+f5 clears the browser cache.  Did you clear Drupal's cache?

Comment: <style type='text/css'></style>
Should be in the <head>

You could add it as an attribute for some element with conditional comments - but it's extra ugly.

Just put ie styles in a separate file and require it in <head>.

Comment: @RooticalV. I agree with you put it in separate file is very better solution